# String splitting on 3 or more words

Tags: java, regex

I have a code that will split 2 words in a string and put them in a array.

```
String words = "chill hit donkey chicken car roast pink rat tree";
```

into

```
[chill hit, donkey chicken, car roast, pink rat, tree]
```

This is my code for that:

```
  String[] result = joined.split("(?<!\\G\\S+)\\s");
  System.out.printf("%s%n", Arrays.toString(result));
```

Now, how do I modify the regex so that it will split into 3 or more words?

Output(3 word in an array):

```
 [chill hit donkey, chicken car roast, pink rat tree]
```

Output(4 word in an array):

```
[chill hit donkey chicken, car roast pink rat tree]
```

Tried to modify regex but nothing had worked this far. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one another `find()` version – just change `{3}` to whatever number you like.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vW1fU0/1)

```
// ((?:\w+\W?){3})(?:(\W+|$))
String text = "chill hit donkey chicken car roast pink rat tree";
String regex = "((?:\\w+\\W?){3})(?:(\\W+|$))";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("'%s'", m.group(1)));
}
```

[Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/0ifGrR)

*Out*

```
'chill hit donkey'
'chicken car roast'
'pink rat tree'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex(using `re.find()`)

```
((?:\w+\s){2}(?:\w+)) (Replace `2` with `3` for 4 words)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qN0wH2/1)**

*Java Code*

```
String line = "chill hit donkey chicken car roast pink rat tree";
String pattern = "((?:\\w+\\s){2}(?:\\w+))";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/5CiZ3g)**

Comment: You should clarify that this is for use with a `find()` loop, not a parameter to `split()`.

Comment: You might want to note in your answer that the OP will need to escape all the backslashes in that regex in the Java string for split.

Comment: @Andreas sorry..had lost my internet connection..updated

Answer (score 1):

for the splitting the text to group of **N** we can use this

**((?:\w+\s){N-1}(?:\w+))** where for group of 2 items you use **((?:\w+\s){1}(?:\w+))**

and for group of 3 items use **((?:\w+\s){2}(?:\w+))** and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the appropriate additional number of "nonwhitespace+whitespace" combinations:

`joined.split("(?<!\\G\\S+\\s+\\S+)\\s");`

You can group the \S+\s+ together if they get larger than this...`

`joined.split("(?<!\\G(\\S+\\s+){2}\\S+)\\s");` for 4 words, etc.